# Adding in expand selection functionality to sort function for a list in a VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I'm on the last step to setting up this simple macro but just can't figure out one part. So in this image:

[image]

When the macro runs, the data sorts successfully, but just that column sorts which means that the order of values in the other columns doesn't change which results in the data getting messed up.

If I did this manually, excel would prompt me asking if I want to expand my selection and I would say yes. Any tips on adding in this functionality would be amazing.

Thank you!!
P.S. I know this approach is a bit simple

```
Sub SortData()

If Range("E17").Value = 1 Then
    Range("E18:E950").Sort Key1:=Range("E18"), Order1:=xlDescending

ElseIf Range("F17").Value = 1 Then
    Range("F18:F950").Sort Key1:=Range("F18"), Order1:=xlDescending

ElseIf Range("G17").Value = 1 Then
    Range("G18:G950").Sort Key1:=Range("G18"), Order1:=xlDescending

ElseIf Range("H17").Value = 1 Then
    Range("H18:H950").Sort Key1:=Range("H18"), Order1:=xlDescending

ElseIf Range("I17").Value = 1 Then
    Range("I18:I950").Sort Key1:=Range("I18"), Order1:=xlDescending

ElseIf Range("J17").Value = 1 Then
    Range("J18:J950").Sort Key1:=Range("J18"), Order1:=xlDescending

Else
    Range("K18:K950").Sort Key1:=Range("K18"), Order1:=xlDescending

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to include the entire range in the sort argument as this is the range that should be sorted. The Key is what determines the column to sort by. Therefore the range should be "E18:K950". So you would have the following:

```
Sub SortData()

If Range("E17").Value = 1 Then
    Range("A18:K950").Sort Key1:=Range("E18"), Order1:=xlDescending

ElseIf Range("F17").Value = 1 Then
    Range("A18:K950").Sort Key1:=Range("F18"), Order1:=xlDescending

ElseIf Range("G17").Value = 1 Then
    Range("A18:K950").Sort Key1:=Range("G18"), Order1:=xlDescending

ElseIf Range("H17").Value = 1 Then
    Range("A18:K950").Sort Key1:=Range("H18"), Order1:=xlDescending

ElseIf Range("I17").Value = 1 Then
    Range("A18:K950").Sort Key1:=Range("I18"), Order1:=xlDescending

ElseIf Range("J17").Value = 1 Then
    Range("A18:K950").Sort Key1:=Range("J18"), Order1:=xlDescending

Else
    Range("A18:K950").Sort Key1:=Range("K18"), Order1:=xlDescending

End If

End Sub
```